# Why this piece is outputting NAN (Not a Number)?

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I am trying to implement closest pair problem using STLs and I am facing an issue particularly in the base condition itself!

This piece of code returns nan while it works if i try to print the distance between (1,1) and (0,0)  . The expected output is some number atleast, I mean I think I am not screwing this up but it is not working !!!!!

Note: I have tried testing distance using
distance( make_pair(make_pair(1,1),make_pair(0,0)))  and it gives correct output. I think something else which is whaat I am missing

The Base Condition (Note I am overusing pair,but that is fine):

```
if(R-L+1<=3)
{
    int i,j;
    double Temp=1000000.00;
    pair < pair < int , int > , pair < int  , int > >ret;
    for(i=L;i<R;++i)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<=R;++j)
        {
            pair < pair < int , int > , pair < int , int > >PEE=make_pair(X[i],X[j]);
            cout<<distance(PEE)<<" ";//This statement outputs nan!!
            if(distance(PEE)<Temp)
            {
                ret=PEE;
                Temp=distance(ret);
            }

        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

That cout statement wont give the correct output !!

Here, ret is the points to return (Closest pair) . Temp for storing the distance.

The Whole Function:

```
pair < pair < int , int > , pair < int , int > > Divide(int L,int R)
{
    if(R-L+1<=3)
    {
        int i,j;
        double Temp=1000000.00;
        pair < pair < int , int > , pair < int  , int > >ret;
        for(i=L;i<R;++i)
        {
            for(j=i+1;j<=R;++j)
            {
                pair < pair < int , int > , pair < int , int > >PEE=make_pair(X[i],X[j]);
                cout<<distance(PEE)<<" ";
                if(distance(PEE)<Temp)
                {
                    ret=PEE;
                    Temp=distance(ret);
                }

            }
        }

        return ret;
    }

    int M=(R+L)/2;
    pair < pair < int , int > , pair < int , int > > P1=Divide(L,M),Chota;
    pair < pair < int , int > , pair < int , int > > P2=Divide(M+1,R);
    double Delta;
    if(distance(P1)<distance(P2))
        {
            Delta=distance(P1);
            Chota=P1;
        }
    else
        {
            Delta=distance(P2);
            Chota=P2;
        }
    pair < pair < int , int > , pair < int , int > > P3=Merge(L,R,Delta);
    if(distance(P3)<distance(Chota))
        return P3;
    else
        return Chota;

}
```

The Distance Function:

```
 double distance(pair < pair < int , int > , pair < int , int > > P)
{
    return (double)sqrt(SQUARE(P.first.first-P.second.first)+SQUARE(P.first.second-P.second.second));
}
```

The Macros for SQUARE:

```
#define SQUARE(x)  (x*x)
#define MOD(X)  (X>0?X:-1*X)
```

Now the whole program just in case you need it.!

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define SQUARE(x)  (x*x)
#define MOD(X)  (X>0?X:-1*X)
using namespace std;
pair < int , int > P[5000+1],X[5000+1],Y[5000+1];

 double distance(pair < pair < int , int > , pair < int , int > > P);

 pair < pair < int , int > , pair < int , int > > Merge(int L , int R, double Delta)
 {
     pair < int , int > Copy[R-L+1],Temp=X[(R+L)/2];
     int i,j,k=0;
     for(i=L;i<=R;++i)
         if(MOD(Temp.first-Y[i].first)<=Delta+1e-9)
            Copy[k++]=Y[i];
     const int Size=k;
     double Dis=10000000;
     pair < pair < int , int > , pair < int , int > > ret;
     for(i=0;i<Size;++i)
     {
         for(j=i+1;j<=i+7 && j<Size; ++j)
            {
                if(distance(make_pair(Copy[i],Copy[j]))<Dis)
                   {
                        ret=make_pair(Copy[i],Copy[j]);
                        Dis=distance(ret);
                   }
            }
     }
     return ret;
 }

pair < pair < int , int > , pair < int , int > > Divide(int L,int R)
{
    if(R-L+1<=3)
    {
        int i,j;
        double Temp=1000000.00;
        pair < pair < int , int > , pair < int  , int > >ret;
        for(i=L;i<R;++i)
        {
            for(j=i+1;j<=R;++j)
            {
                pair < pair < int , int > , pair < int , int > >PEE=make_pair(X[i],X[j]);
                cout<<distance(PEE)<<" ";
                if(distance(PEE)<Temp)
                {
                    ret=PEE;
                    Temp=distance(ret);
                }

            }
        }

        return ret;
    }

    int M=(R+L)/2;
    pair < pair < int , int > , pair < int , int > > P1=Divide(L,M),Chota;
    pair < pair < int , int > , pair < int , int > > P2=Divide(M+1,R);
    double Delta;
    if(distance(P1)<distance(P2))
        {
            Delta=distance(P1);
            Chota=P1;
        }
    else
        {
            Delta=distance(P2);
            Chota=P2;
        }
    pair < pair < int , int > , pair < int , int > > P3=Merge(L,R,Delta);
    if(distance(P3)<distance(Chota))
        return P3;
    else
        return Chota;

}

bool cmp(pair < int , int > A , pair < int , int > B){return A.second<B.second;}
int main()
{


    int N,i;
    scanf("%d",&N);
    for(i=0;i<N;++i)
        {
            scanf("%d%d",&P[i].first,&P[i].second);
            Y[i]=X[i]=P[i];
        }

    sort(X,X+N);
    sort(Y,Y+N,cmp);
    Divide(0,N-1);
    return 0;
}

 double distance(pair < pair < int , int > , pair < int , int > > P)
{
    return (double)sqrt(SQUARE(P.first.first-P.second.first)+SQUARE(P.first.second-P.second.second));
}
```

Comment: Please construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Check if the argument of `sqrt` is not negative.

Comment: As an aside instead of using those macros why not just write real functions perhaps with `constexpr`? And I'd use `abs` instead of the `MOD` macro.

Comment: @AlexD - SQUARE of sum of Two numbers is always non negative I guess! And I am trying to improve

Comment: @ShubhamSharma `SQUARE(x)  (x*x)` should be `SQUARE(x)  ((x)*(x))`, if you really want defines.

Comment: Ok , please vote to close !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#define SQUARE(x)  (x*x)
```

may results in a negative value, e.g.

```
cout << SQUARE(-1-2) << endl;
```

gets resolved in `-1 - 2*-1 - 2` and produces `-1`.

It is much better to avoid macros, but if you use this one, make it

```
#define SQUARE(x)  ((x)*(x))
```

Answer (score 2):

Running this through the preprocessing step with `g++ -E` shows the problem that results from your macro usage really clearly. Before preprocessing:

```
 double distance(pair < pair < int , int > , pair < int , int > > P)
{
    return (double)sqrt(SQUARE(P.first.first-P.second.first)+SQUARE(P.first.second-P.second.second));
}
```

after preprocessing:

```
double distance(pair < pair < int , int > , pair < int , int > > P)
{
return (double)sqrt((P.first.first-P.second.first*P.first.first-P.second.first)+(P.first.second-P.second.second*P.first.second-P.second.second));
}
```

This is almost certainly not what you want. As you can see this can produce a negative argument to `sqrt` which will then give you the NaN that you are seeing.

To write the macro properly you can see AlexD's answer but honestly I think the better approach here is to not use a macro and just use a function for the square and the `abs` function from the standard library.

Comment: Actually , i am sleepy i though i parenthised the expression and then i was taking square of it!